# remove duplicates from the data returned (rows)

Tags: sql

how do you remove duplicates from the data returned (rows) of a select statement.

its probably something easy but I'm having trouble with it

Comment: Why does the query return duplicate rows? This question is almost always indicative of an incorrect query, most likely an incorrect join.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `SELECT DISTINCT ...` [read more](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/).

Comment: would that be all i have to add

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want - yes. But why don't you just try it?